# Process Builder not working as expected

Tags: trigger, process-builder, workflow, leads, tasks

I have a process builder that works as follows:

- When Approver 1 approves the lead record, field 1 on the lead will be updated, and based on that task 1 will be updated
- When Approver 2 approves the same record, field 2 on the lead will be updated, and based on that task 2 will be updated

Here, the issue is that the lead field is updating successfully but the task is not getting updated until or unless I manually edit and save the lead record.

Is this the expected behaviour or Am I missing anything here?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, a field update from an approval process should definitely be able to fire a process builder.  Make sure you have the "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules After Field Change" checkbox checked.

However, there are limitations for related objects.  See the below document, which lists cross-object field considerations:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_field_update_considerations.htm&type=5

Also, there's no direct link between Lead and Task.  The "Related To" field is polymorphic, which means it can't be used like a standard lookup field.  So I' suprised you got the process builder to work.  But, assuming it does, the "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules After Field Change" checkbox should accomplish what you need.

Comment: even when the checkbox is checked, until or unless I manually update the lead, task is not getting updated. Do we have any work around for this?

Comment: I'm stumped.  A valid field update from an approval process should be able to fire a process builder.  The only other thing to check is to confirm the approval process field update is definitely firing the exact same update that you are doing when manually saving the record.